# Bullseye coverage for embedded systems - not a small footprint data file

Tags: uefi, efi, footprint, bullseye

I'm fighting for few weeks with Bullseye run for EFI (EDK II) system.
I finally linked everything, compiled the code and everything seems to work (I used Bullseye tutorial for embedded system and this topic: [Bullseye for EDK Based Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599140/bullseye-for-edk-based-application)).

I ran the tests and received symbols for Bullseye COV file. According to the second link:

> The output data can be redirected to a file (using the > directive
>   inside EDK2 shell) and then be processed by covpost to be merged into
>   the cov file created in the build process.

I redirected this output to file, but when trying to merge into the COV file I get the message:

> **Copyright (c) Bullseye Testing Technology 1990-2014**
>
> **Exception: be_test: not a small footprint data file**

Some ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "when trying to merge into the COV file"?  I have used Bullseye in a different embedded environment, so maybe my experience is different.  From what I've seen, the COV file is generated during compilation and is essentially a list of the files/functions being covered.  The coverage output will be a separate file type, and isn't "merged" into the COV file.  As I said, my platform/workflow might be different though...

Comment: If I understand right, after compilation I receive COV file with 0% coverage and after running test I get "footprint information", which I need to "merge" to COV file using "covpost" binary, for check coverage of this tests.

Comment: Perhaps the small footprint data file ("be_test" I presume?) is malformed.  Seems to be what the error is indicating.  Maybe you have some extra text at the header/footer that shouldn't be there?  I've ran into that issue before.  Also, did you run covpost in the same directory as the COV file and coverage file?

Comment: I made alias, but using covpost from the same directory doesn't solve the problem. Maybe footprint data file is malformed, because I copied it from serial console output. But when it starts with line: --- BullseyeCoverage begin file 'BlsyCvrg.aa1', data begins next line --- and ends with:--- BullseyeCoverage end file ---, everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bullseye may throw this error due to nothing *actually* being under test. In my case, I had only written a mockup of the test, I had no actual "source" file that my test ran against. When I added some dummy logic to test, this error was resolved.

It would be worth checking that all your files are being compiled as you expect them to and you actually have something in your project's source that is being tested. Based on OP saying this is a new setup, there is a chance something similar occurred.

Answer (score 0):

After removing header and footer now the covpost gives the following complaint Exception: unexpected end of input in BullseyeCoverage.data-1

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. The solution is very simple - you have to delete first and last line in .data file:
--- BullseyeCoverage begin file 'BullseyeCoverage.data-1', data begins next line --- <<<<----- delete it
--- BullseyeCoverage end <<<<----- delete it